# Preallocate memory for a program in Linux before it gets started

Tags: linux, memory, scientific-computing

I have a program that repeatedly solves large systems of linear equations using cholesky decomposition. Characterising  is that I sometimes need to store the complete factorisation which can exceed about 20 GB of memory. The factorisation happens inside a library that I call. Furthermore, this matrix and the resulting factorisation changes quite frequently and as such the memory requirements as well.

I am not the only person to use this compute-node. Therefore, **is there a way to start the program under Linux and preallocate free memory for the process**?

Something like: `$: prealloc -m 25G ./program`

Answer (score 0):

I'll stick my neck out and say that I don't think that there is such a way under Linux.  I think that the philosophy of Linux (and every other multi-tasking o/s I've used or heard of) is to provide the programmer (and the program) with the illusion that they have the whole of the computer's memory to play with and to make it very difficult indeed for a programmer to interfere with the o/s.

Instead, I think that you should plan to modify your program to grab the memory it will (or may) require when it starts up, that is, do the memory management yourself in whatever your chosen language is.  How easy this might be for you, considering calls to a library, I don't know.

Comment: No, unfortunately this is not an option. Anyway, thank you for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

I've never heard of such a way. Usually it would be bad for other users on the node if one program went ahead and hogged all available memory. It's not good practice.

But opinions aside, I would probably write my program in such a way that it acts like a small environment that is able to make multiple runs of the routine in question without ending. It would allocate lots of memory on startup, then wait for user commands (through a minimal shell) and make the runs requested with the allocated memory pool. It would hold on to the pool until the user requests termination.

Of course this requires you to have an interactive session on the node, which you may not have.